# AVALONIA: Binding Button to method to add info in Datagrid

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagrid, reactiveui, avaloniaui

So, I created a Button control in a DataGrid, that Adds New people information to the DataGrid.
Like this:

```
`<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add New Person" Margin="5" Command="{Binding AddNewPerson}"/>
    <DataGrid Items="{Binding People}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" 
                                Binding="{Binding FirstName}" 
                                Width="2*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" 
                                Binding="{Binding LastName}" 
                                Width="2*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" 
                                Binding="{Binding DepartmentNumber}" 
                                Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>`
```

Now, when I try writing the function to bind the button with, the following snippet:

```
 public ReactiveCommand AddNewPerson { get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>(GenerateMockPeopleTable());
        AddNewPerson = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        {
            People.Add(
                new Person()
                {
                    FirstName = "New First Name", 
                    LastName = "New Last Name"
                });
        });
```

I get the following errors:

```
1. 'ReactiveCommand':static types cannot be used as return types.
2.Cannot Implicitly convert type 'ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand<System.Reactive.Unit,System.Reactive.Unit> to .ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand'
```

Would be really helpful if someone could provide some guidance!

Comment: what is the definition of `AddNewPerson`

Answer (score 1):

Your property `public ReactiveCommand AddNewPerson { get; }` doesn't have a valid type - you cannot create a non-generic ReactiveCommand, only `ReactiveCommand<TInput, TOutput>`.

Change it to `public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> AddNewPerson { get; }` and it'll  work.